# Differences in sys.path when python2.7 is invoked normally or via subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, python-3.4, sys.path

### Question

Why is it that `python2.7` when called using a subprocess via `python3` does
not have the same sys.path as `python2.7` called normally? Specifically,
`python2.7` via subprocess does not have the `"/path/to/site-packages/"` 
directory in sys.path.

### Context

I'd like to use `fabric` to deploy a Django app I'm writing. My problem is that
I've written the app in `python3`, but `fabric` doesn't have explicit `python3`
support yet. My workaround, until `fabric` is fully compatible with `python3`,
is to call the `fab` script using `subprocess`.

For some reason when I call `python2.7` using `subprocess` via `python3`, I
don't have access to any modules in `site-packages`.

### python2.7 checks

I've got `python2.7` and `fabric==1.10.0` installed via Enthought.

```
$ which python
/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.6 --  32-bit

$ which fab
/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/fab

$ fab --version
Fabric 1.10.0
Paramiko 1.15.1
```

### subprocess checks

I have no problem calling `fab` from within `python2.7` using subprocess.

```
$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 32-bit | (default, Apr 11 2014, 12:06:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('fab --version', shell=True)
'Fabric 1.10.0\nParamiko 1.15.1\n'
```

I also have no problem calling `python2.7` from within `python3` using subprocess.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('which python', shell=True)
b'/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output('python --version', shell=True)
Python 2.7.6 --  32-bit
b''
```

### DistributionNotFound: Fabric==1.10.0

However, even though my subprocess of `python2.7` can "find" the fab script, I
can't call it.

```
# python3
>>> subprocess.check_output(['which', 'fab'])
b'/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/fab\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(['fab', '--version'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2877, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.0.1938.macosx-x86/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 596, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Fabric==1.10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['fab', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

### site-packages not in sys.path

It appears that `python2.7` when called using subprocess via `python3` does
not have the same sys.path as `python2.7` called normally.

As expected, sys.path did not have the Enthought `"site-packages"` directory,
which contains the `fabric` module.

```
# python3
>>> subprocess.check_output('python -c "import sys; print sys.path"', shell=True)
## does not contain '/path/to/Enthought/python2.7/site-packages'
```

### Manually add site-packages to sys.path

To confirm that it's possible: when I manually add the correct
`"site-packages"` directory, I can successfully import `fabric`.

```
# python3
>>> subprocess.check_output('python -c\
    "import sys; sys.path.append(\'/path/to/Enthought/site-packages\');\
    from fabric import version; print version.get_version()"',\
    shell = True)
b'1.10.0\n'
```

### Other options?

There's got to be a better way to make sure that python2.7, when
invoked via subprocess from python3, has the same sys.path as `python2.7`
invoked normally. Can someone more familiar with subprocess weigh in?

### Additional thoughts

It's really interesting that `python2.7` can spawn another `python2.7` 
via subprocess and that subprocess *has* the correct site-packages dir
in sys.path.

```
$ python
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('python -c "import sys; print sys.path"', shell=True)
## contains "/path/to/Enthought/python2.7/site-packages"
```

I also compared the `sys.path`'s from python3, python3 subprocessed by python3, 
and python3 subprocessed by python2.7, and was a bit surprised to find that
all three resulted in the same `sys.path`.

Comment: Could you run `python -m site` both outside and inside the subprocess call and see if there are significant differences?

Comment: @SimeonVisser No differences in the `python -m site` variables sys.path, USER_BASE, USER_SITE, ENABLE_USER_SITE. Surprisingly, sys.path from inside the subprocess call contains the missing paths (e.g., `"/path/to/Enthought/python2.7/site-packages"`). Any chance that's a clue?

Comment: Although `fab` is an executable, it still needs a Python interpreter to run (it's a Python script). Can you do `head /Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/fab` and see what Python interpreter is listed at the top?

Comment: The correct python interpreter is listed. `#!/Users/.../Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python`.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean "sys.path from inside the subprocess call contains the missing paths", vs the second sentence in your question which seems to state the opposite?

Comment: Any differences in the environment variables in your subprocess spawned from Python3 vs in terminal?

Comment: @JonathanMarch the sys.path variable from python -m site differs from import sys; print sys.path when called from within a python2.7 subprocess when spawned from python3 but not from python2.7.

Comment: I'm asking about the output from the bash `env` command, i.e. the set of all environment variables.

Comment: @JonathanMarch The output from `env` differs when spawned from Python3 vs in the terminal in two ways: Python3's subprocess `env` has a `__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__` path to my framework build of python3, and has `SHLVL=2`. From the terminal, `env` does not contain the `__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__` and has `SHLVL=1`.

Comment: Interesting. Try removing `__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__` before starting python 2.7.

Comment: You're on to something, @JonathanMarch. Removing `__PYVENV_LAUNCHER__` works. From within python3: `subprocess.check_output("unset __PYVENV_LAUNCHER__ && python -c 'from fabric import version; print version.get_version()'", shell = True)` returns the correct version of fabric (1.10.0). Turn any suggestions as to how to unset that variable into an answer and I'd really appreciate it. Here's one way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747122/calling-python-scripts-from-inside-python

Answer (score 0):

[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) supports an `env` parameter that, if given, will be the environment for the called command -- so make a copy of it, remove any troublesome variables, and pass that copy to `subprocess`:

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
del my_env['__PYENV_LAUNCHER__']
subprocess.check_output(..., env=my_env)
```